# Change the position of Map point without changing zoom level or span

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am using following codes

```
 MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annView.annotation.coordinate.latitude, annView.annotation.coordinate.longitude - .04), Some KM, Some KM);

 MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
 [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

Otherway around is

```
MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annView.annotation.coordinate.latitude, annView.annotation.coordinate.longitude - .04), ADD SPAN HERE)
```

Both of these makes the map zoom. How is it possible that I change the Region without any zoom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the current region and just change the center point.

```
// get current region
MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
// Update the center
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annView.annotation.coordinate.latitude, annView.annotation.coordinate.longitude - .04);
// apply the new region
self.mapView.region = region;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a coordinate to set, use the `MKMapView` `-setCenterCoordinate:animated:` method. Animating the position change gives the user a clue about what's happened.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = annView.annotation.coordinate;
[myMapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:YES];
```

Also, no need to make a new coordinate, just use the one already in the annotation view.